# GetFeatureInfo query only for visible layers in OpenLayers 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, openlayers, openlayers-6

I'm a newby with JS and OL, and I have an Openlayers 6 map with different WMS layers grouped into several `ol.layer.Group`. I want to request feature information through "getGetFeatureInfoUrl". Visibility of layers can be turned on/off in the layer tree. I'd like to, upon clicking somewhere in the map:

- Get Feature Info ONLY for layers that are currently visible
- and, if there are more than one layers at the chosen location, get the Feature Info for all of them

This code works well for just one layer (wmsLayer5, in this case)

```
map.on('singleclick', function (evt) {
if (!wmsLayer5.getVisible()) return;
document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
const viewResolution = /** @type {number} */ (vista.getResolution());
const url = wmsLayer5.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(
    evt.coordinate,
    viewResolution,
    'EPSG:25830',
    {'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html'}
    );
    if (url) {
        fetch(url)
        .then((response) => response.text())
        .then((html) => {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;
        });
    }
});
```

But I need a code to iterate over all layers and only call getFeatureInfo if they are visible. I've tried this one, but doesn't work and doesn't return any message in the console

```
map.on('singleclick', function (evt1) {
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = '';
            var viewResolution = /** @type {number} */
            (vista.getResolution());
            var url = '';
            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML ='';
            layers.forEach(function (layer, i, layers) {
                if (layer.getVisible() ) {
                    url = layer.getSource().getGetFeatureInfoUrl(
                        evt1.coordinate, 
                        viewResolution, 
                        'EPSG:25830', {
                        'INFO_FORMAT': 'text/html',
                            'FEATURE_COUNT': '300'
                    });
                    if (url) {
                        fetch(url)
                        .then((response) => response.text())
                        .then((html) => {
                            document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += html;
                        });
                    }
                }
            });
        
        });
```

Any suggestion to fix it?

Comment: If you expect results from multiple layers you will need to change `document.getElementById('info').innerHTML = html;` to `document.getElementById('info').innerHTML += html;` to display more than one.

Comment: I've changed that, but still doesn't work. No error messages in the console either.

Comment: You should use method "forEachLayerAtPixel"
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/apidoc/module-ol_Map-Map.html#forEachLayerAtPixel

let pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(evt1.coordinate);

Comment: @ivom it seems that this method is deprecated, isn't it? Anyway, I'd need a slightly more detailed description since my knowledge on these matters is quite restricted.

Answer (score 0):

This method has been deprecated since version 6.13 (4 months ago) and won't be changed before next major release. I didn't use suggested replacement `layer.getData()`. Following code iterates through all the layers and queries only visible ones and of type Image.

```
    map.on("click", onMouseClick);
    function onMouseClick(browserEvent) {
        let coordinate = browserEvent.coordinate;
        let pixel = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(coordinate);
        map.forEachLayerAtPixel(pixel, function (layer) {
            if (layer instanceof ol.layer.Image) {
                if (layer.get("visible")) {
                    let url = layer.getSource().getFeatureInfoUrl(coordinate, map.getView().getResolution(), "EPSG:3857", {
                        INFO_FORMAT: "application/json",
                    });
                    if (url) {
                        fetch(url)
                            .then(function (response) {
                                return response.text();
                            })
                            .then(function (json) {
                                let data = JSON.parse(json);
                                if (data.features.length > 0) {
                                    //Do something with data.features
                                }
                            });
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: I've tried it, using console.log(data.features) in the "if" clause, but nothing appears in the console.